# Does zero resistance mean that there are no energy exchanging processes between particles in superconductor?

Tags: superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate

I was just knowing little bit about bose einstein condensate then I came across superconductor. In the  bose einstein condensate particles have same energy levels and they can not escape the level or can't  change their energy. Now I can't find the reason why anything should have near zero resistance for this. So my question is how does no energy change of the particles cause zero or near zero resistance   ?

Comment: Resistance is not something you apply is a property of a given system.

Comment: @Mauricio great suggestion.  Is it okay now?

Comment: Again resistance is not a cause but a result. I would prefer to ask, does zero resistance means that there are no energy exchanging processes between particles? But I'm not sure if that is your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intuitive reasons for superconductivity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28699/)

Comment: @JohnRennie you should close it as duplicate  . I got the answer.