# Why is a bosonic condensate not easy to be scattered in a superconductor?

Tags: fermions, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate

Why does an individual fermionic electron scatter off lattice defects easily while the Cooper pairs are insusceptible? I know they condensate to a same macroscopic quantum state, but still, why can such a condensate flow effortlessly? What happens when one pair scatter off the lattice? Is there any close analogy?

Comment: See also [Intuitive reasons for superconductivity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28699/intuitive-reasons-for-superconductivity).